# creating transperent button in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, button, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a cocos2d game. In that game I hace a character, and according to the touch positions on the caracter different actions should be triggered,How can i Implement this in my cocos2d game.
Is there any method to implement transparent button in cocos2d.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you create a CCMenuItemSprite (a button), you assign it a sprite to use for display.

You can then change the appearance of the button by changing the opacity property of the sprite, or by making it not visible at all.

```
CCSprite *buttonSpr = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"spr.png"];

CCMenuItem *button = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:buttonSpr selectedSprite:buttonSpr target:self selector:@selector(buttonTapped:)];

//opacity
buttonSpr.opacity = 50;

//invisible
buttonSpr.visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand the question and more information would be helpful, but I'll answer it the best I can.

Assuming you have a character class I would implement checkTouchesBegan and do something like this:

```
-(BOOL) checkTouchesBegan: (CGPoint*) location
{
//conver the touch coordinates to fit your system
int converty = location->y-160;
int convertx = location->x-240;

//determine where the touch is in relation to the center of the character
float ydif = (1.0)*(converty - character_y);
float xdif = (1.0)*(convertx - character_x);

//determine the angle of the touch
float degrees = atan2f(xdif, ydif) * 57;
//determine the distance between the character and the touch
float squared = xdif*xdif + ydif*ydif;

//if the touch is above the character and within a certain distance
if(degrees >= 45 && degrees < 135 && sqrt(squared) < 100)
{
  doSomething;
  return YES;
}
//if the touch is below the character and within a certain distance
else if(degrees < -45 && degrees >= -135 && sqrt(squared) < 100)
{
 doSomething;
 return YES;
}
//if the touch is to the right of the character and within a certain distance
else if(degrees >= -45 && degrees < 45 && sqrt(squared) < 100)
{
 doSomething;
 return YES;
}
//if the touch is to the left of the character and within a certain distance
else if(sqrt(squared) < 100)
{
 doSomething;
 return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

Hope this helps some!